# PDF Blob is showing nothing in new tab, using stream from backend

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I used https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
stream method for sending a response to front-end.
Here is my code which I wrote for opening pdf in a new tab.I'm calling stream from backend API in result it gives a response but when I try to create blob it shows nothing in PDF.

```
APICaller({
  method: 'get',
  responseType: "arraybuffer",
   headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/pdf'
  },
  endpoint: gep('generate/certificate?path=certificate.pdf', 'v3'),
}).then( (data) => {
   var file = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   window.open(fileURL);

});
```

[here is Empty PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8G9L.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with axios, it doesn't work for downloading files using Blob. Use XMLHttpRequest and do the similar response handler in its `on('load')` event to achieve file download.